# String split out of memory

Tags: java, string, split, out-of-memory, large-data

I have a large collection of tab separated text data in the form of `DATE NAME MESSAGE`. By large I mean, a collection of 1.76GB divided into 1075 actual files. I have to get the `NAME` data from *all* the files. Till now I have this:

```
   File f = new File(directory);
        File files[] = f.listFiles();
        // HashSet<String> all = new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> userCount = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                BufferedReader in;
                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        // if (all.add(str)) {
                        userCount.add(str.split("\t")[1]);
                        // }

                        // if (all.size() > 500)
                        // all.clear();
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Something went wrong: "
                            + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
```

My program is always giving out of memory exception even with -Xmx1700. I cannot go beyond that. Is there anyway I can optimize the code so that it can handle the `ArrayList<String>` of `NAME`s?

Comment: Does this need to be a java program? Could you use linux/unix tools for this?  Windows batch?

Comment: it does not have to be a java program, but I don't know how to use Linux tools for this. My objective here is to count the number of messages per user which ranges between 1-200. Also, same users are clustered together, but can be divided into two separate files linearly.

Comment: Consider using [StreamTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) to split the characters as you read them, rather than reading first and then splitting.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data? Can you not process the data as you get it, rather than build a list which is too large, before you do you real processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be allowing alternative solutions than Java, here's an awk one that should handle it.

```
cat *.txt | awk -F'\t' '{sum[$2] += 1} END {for (name in sum) print name "," sum[name]}'
```

Explanation:

```
-F'\t' - separate on tabs
sum[$2] += 1 - increment the value for the second element (name)
```

Associative arrays make this extremely succinct. Running it on a test file I created as follows:

```
import random

def main():
    names = ['Nick', 'Frances', 'Carl']
    for i in range(10000):
        date = '2012-03-24'
        name = random.choice(names)
        message = 'asdf'
        print '%s\t%s\t%s' %(date, name, message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the results:

```
Carl,3388
Frances,3277
Nick,3335
```

Comment: awesome. this helped me! I need to learn more about linux scripting. Thank you very much. Also, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `grep` and `awk` are very powerful. Learn them and prosper.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do to improve the memory footprint and general performance of your code:

1. Close your FileReader objects before moving on to the next one.  [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) is an InputStreamReader, which needs to call `close()` in order to free up resources.  Your current code is effectively keeping a stream open for every file you're looking at.

   ```
   for( File file: files ) {
       BufferedReader in = null;
       try{
           in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
           // TODO do whatever you want here.
       }
       finally{
           if( in != null ) {
               in.close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If possible, eliminate storing all of your `NAME` values in the `userCount` ArrayList.  Like A. R. S. suggested, you can write this information to another file first, and then just read the file when you need to pull that data again.  If that's not an attractive option, you could still write your information to an OutputStream which is then piped to an InputStream elsewhere in your app.  This would keep your data in memory, but wherever you're using the list of `NAME` values could begin processing/displaying/whatever concurrently, as you continue to read through these 1,000+ files searching for more `NAME` values.
3. Use the [listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method so Java can filter out non-text files for you.  This should prevent a few extra CPU cycles, as you would no longer have to iterate over files with the incorrect extension before eliminating them.

Answer (score 1):

String.split returns Strings that use internally the same array of chars than the original String. The unused chars will not be garbage collected.

Try using new String( str.split("\t")[1]) to force the allocation of a new array.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work either. When doing a split, internally there's an array that contains all the parts of the original string. So it does not make any difference. But, thank you for the comment.