# Prepare a correlation matrix of huge text files

Tags: string, split, out-of-memory, text-files, large-data

I have two directories of text files. One has the `User Description` and the other has `User Messages` with fields `DATE<\t>NAME<\t>DESCRIPTION` and `DATE<\t>NAME<\t>MESSAGE`. My main objective is to get correlation matrix between the profile and message words between these two files.

One example would be:

```
                              *message words*
                          cat     dog    mouse ....
*profile words*    cat    100     20      50
                   dog     2      30      22  ...
                   ...
                   ...
```

Here, the number 100 between cat and cat means "the word "cat" appeared 100 times in all messages written by any user with "cat" in their profile description".

I tried to solve this problem using Java, but even a much simpler version of this program did not run because of the size of the text files. Here's the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360046/string-split-out-of-memory) I posted few days ago. The `awk` tool did solve my previous problem.

My question is, is there any efficient way to solve this type of problem? I do not have language restrictions. Also, I have some knowledge in bash utilities like diff, cat, etc.

Just for information, my `User Messages` has 1.7G of multiple text files. `User Description` is around 400M also with multiple files. The most memory I can give to Java is -Xmx1800m.

Also, if this is not a valid question, please let me know. I will remove the post.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look at Lucene library it is originated from java but also ported to C# and C++ (at least).

What you do is called "indexing" - you create document, (for example it can be associated with simple file). Each document can contain  optional fields - directory where the file appears.   After that it is very easy to count number of particular words or even more word-forms (like a cat vs cats)